# How do I verify a ECDSA signature?

Tags: sendgrid

I am using SendGrid to receive event notifications when emails are delivered, clicked, etc.

They have this "verification" key that they give me and say they use ECDSA to generate public/private key pairs. They gave me a key without telling me what it is, I am assuming it is the public key.

So then when sending the data they give me a signature with a timestamp and the body.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook-security-features/#manage-the-signed-event-webhook-using-the-api

I have the following NodeJS code but really don't know how to approach this. The example object in the buffer is what SG sends.

```
    const ts = res.headers["X-Twilio-Email-Event-Webhook-Timestamp"];


    const msg = Buffer.of(ts, [
        {
            "email": "iekchimzie1@gmail.com",
            "event": "open",
            "ip": "66.249.93.222",
            "sg_content_type": "html",
            "sg_event_id": "fRVFj9NaRPuLtgrTJcRZYA",
            "sg_message_id": "DZqeK1BjQN-5yOUCykR7WQ.filterdrecv-p3iad2-8ddf98858-xxtk7-19-5EC1C6BE-4F.0",
            "sg_template_id": "d-31ad8dd470384ad1aa6f4dc557f7ee65",
            "sg_template_name": "Untitled_11565020537169",
            "timestamp": 1590198073,
            "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)"
        }
    ]);
    const shaMsg = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(msg).digest()

    const isValid = ecdsa.verify(shaMsg, evSig, SG_WEBHOOK_V_KEY);
```

Comment: I am struggling with this one as well. Can I ask, what is the ```ecdsa``` object you use when calling ```ecdsa.verify(...)```? Also, the ```msg``` buffer you create from the ```ts``` and the payload object, why do you construct it like that? I'm sure you are right; I'm asking since I'm trying to understand it myself.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecdsa-secp256r1

My code doesn't work though.

Comment: Yeah... I gave up. What I did was to take the request, treat it as possibly malicious and then verify with a call from the back end to check on the actual status of the system supposedly sending me the request. So, their request acts as a sort of trigger, but I then ask for the data I actually work on.

Comment: I guess it's not that important. I mean, it's not like some hacker is going gain anything by faking email event webhooks. It's more of a have not. And besides it's in beta so we shouldn't be using it for production.

Comment: And, like I wrote above, whatever it is that they might have faked, you could verify. E.g. in my case, I reacted to unsubscribe events. Well, when I get a unsubscribe event, I then query SendGrid about the supposedly unsubscribed email. If it truly is unsubscribed, do what I meant to do. If not, call the cops. :-)